# Material UI use primary and secondary in makeStyles

Tags: material-ui

I am setting the background color of a Drawer component using useStyle. if i set `background: 'red'` it works fine. But setting it to `background: 'primary'` doesnt work. What might i be doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  
  drawer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    background: 'primary',
  },
}));

<Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant='persistent'
        anchor='top'
        open={true}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
```

Comment: Did you try to access the primary color as `theme.palette.primary.main`?

Comment: I did now and it works. But is there a reason why 'primary' doesnt?

Comment: Can you explain why you think “primary” should work?

Comment: Well i see it being used in Material UI docs.
example
'const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
}));

const defaultProps = {
  color: 'secondary',
  children: <MailIcon />,
};'
in Maximum value example in badges https://material-ui.com/components/badges/  for ex

Comment: Yes, but it is used for props not styles. The props drive logic in the component for using colors from the theme in the styles.

Comment: Ok so i understand that using primary and secondary inside the useStyles hook is not possible. I should always use the way Manu proposed? thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(({ palette }) => ({
    drawerPaper: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      background: palette.primary.main,
    },
}));
```

`makeStyles` function contain the option param which has a palette, theme colors in it. so you can use palette.primary.main or others.

more see(mui v4 version): https://v4.mui.com/zh/system/palette/#palette